# A most expensive energy supply - what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am eaten yet I am sold,
>   People don't even like me or so I've been told.
>
> The real me is wild and rare,
>   Batteries eat me in despair.
>
> Energy I will always supply,
>   Though I am so costly it will make you cry.
>
> Black or brown, but always hot,
>   Don't forget me because then I am not.
>
> Ingested by both animal and man,
>   Do you now know what I am?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated answer:

> [Kopi Luwak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kopi_Luwak) Coffee

```
I am eaten yet I am sold,
People don't even like me or so I've been told.
```

> Might be a reference to the partially digested varieties of coffee like Kopi Luwak or Black Ivory

```
The real me is wild and rare,
Batteries eat me in despair.
```

> [Civets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asian_palm_civet) do actually eat coffee "cherries" as part of their diet but one would be hard pressed to find the "end product" in the wild. This brings us to the "batteries" which is the way Kopi Luwak is mass produced. The animals are held in battery cage systems and are being force fed the coffee cherries.

```
Energy I will always supply,
Though I am so costly it will make you cry.
```

> Coffee will surely give you a boost of energy but it's expensive (around €550/kg)

```
Black or brown, but always hot,
Don't forget me because then I am not.
```

> The coffee drink is black or brown (if you add milk or cream to it) and it's made with boiling water but if you leave it over the heat source too long it will evaporate.

```
Ingested by both animal and man
```

> Well, humans drink it while animals eat the "cherries" of the coffee tree or shrub because of their fleshy pulp.

Comment: Very, very close. Solve all the lines and you know the exact answer.

Comment: Maybe it's not coffee, but cocoa. Many of the things written here fit it as well, with the added bonus that ground cocoa is fed to chickens ("batteries") sometimes. Pure cocoa also tastes weird.

Comment: Might be "caffeine" the active ingredient in coffee. I found quite a lot of info about batteries that use ground coffee as "fuel".

Comment: Is it perhaps specifically kopi luwak coffee? Made from beans that have been ingested and then excreted by civets ("ingested ..."); very expensive ("so costly..."); the civets are often battery-farmed ("batteries eat me ..."); generally scoffed at by coffee experts ("people don't even like me ...").

Comment: I was thinking "Batteries" could mean a military unit, who drink really crappy coffee on the field.

Comment: Perfect! This is the correct answer!

Answer (score 4):

Are you:

> Coal

I am eaten yet I am sold:

> Coal was burned. But used for generating Electricity.

People don't even like me or so I've been told.

> Many people don't like to touch it.

The real me is wild and rare.

> It is available rarely.

Energy I will always supply

> Used for supplying energy(electricity)

Though I am so costly it will make you cry.

> Coal is costlier.

Black or brown, but always hot

> Coal is available in black or brown. If it heated, it will be hot.

Don't forget me because then I am not.

> If it is neglected(used too much quantity). It vanishes so fastly.

Ingested by both animal and man

> Used as medicine for Human and animals. Example - Charcoal. Coal is also used to purify impurities in water.

Comment: Nice try, but no!

Comment: "Batteries eat me in despair"?

Comment: this is actually one of the cheapest sources of energy

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> Radioactive material

Because:

I am eaten yet I am sold,
People don't even like me or so I've been told.

> Everything is a bit radioactive, so everything you eat is radioactive, plutonium (for instance) is sold. Most people don't like the idea of radioactivity, since it can be dangerous for a human.

The real me is wild and rare,
Batteries eat me in despair.

> To get radioactive material is really hard and to find it nature is very rare. A lot of batteries are charge by nuclear plant.

Energy I will always supply,
Though I am so costly it will make you cry.

> Radioactive material will never stop being radioactive, though after a long time it is very small. It is very expensive to buy radioactive materials (again think of plutonium)

Black or brown, but always hot,
Don't forget me because then I am not.

> When in a nuclear ractor a the plutonium is brown because it is hot. If you forget about the radioactive materials, you will always see it's track throughout nature, so you'll never forget...

Ingested by both animal and man,

> Like I said, all food is a tiny bit radioactive, so ingested by animal and man

Comment: Nice try as well, but no!